# Restrict users from clicking a button if other user is on same button(App is in Shared folder which can be accessed by multiple users)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have succesfully developed and deployed an appliation which has a menu (Menu has lot of buttons when a button is clicked it opens different form).The exe is in a shared folder and this folder is accessible to multiple users. My question is if a user opens this application and clicked a specific button then I want to lock that button so that any other user shouldnt be able to click this button from any other machine. How do I acheive this?

Here is a solution I thought of but want to see if there is a better way. As soon as a users clicks a button make an entry in database with the button name and delete it as soon as the form is closed. and I can check the database every time a button is clicked to see if there is a entry in the database if not I will open the form.

I want to use single exe file for all the code to make the maintenance simpler.So i cannot make multiple exes for each form.

Comment: What will happen if your form/app crashes after having locked the button? Have you thought about a _reset_ mode to free eventually locked buttons?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"I want to use single exe file for all the code to make the maintenance simpler"*, but different users are running different instances of the application. I.e., they have different versions of all the variables and forms and buttons. Even several users have started this application, this does not involve multi-threading. Can you explain why you need to lock this button?

Comment: That's a very/too broad question I believe. But to give a pointer: If you have a database in the background you could use its locking mechanism. Otherwise you have to look into the field of IPC.

Comment: @Steve. Thanks for your response didnt think of that but will implement something to free the locked buttons if the app crashes.

Comment: This might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: we are replacing a existing solution and it currently has this feature where a button will be locked if any other user is already on the button.So we are trying to Mimic it. The main reason to Mimic it is to avoid the Training to users, and one of our requirement is that user interface shouldnt change.

Comment: Yes you will need some sort of server resources to hold the state of the button, also you will need to take care of race conditions (ideally through concurrency checking) and take care of any crashes or abnormal closure

Comment: And don't forget to handle the case where a user opens the form and then forgets to close it before going home or out for lunch. Really I can't understand the reason behind this requirement. It makes your life very hard. Probably it is better to understand and remove the reasons that block the concurrent use of the same piece of code.